# Align the icon and title in the button with each other in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to display a list of buttons on a single screen, with the icon displayed at the leading of each button.

I want to align the buttons on the screen based on the button with the longest content. Icons and titles line up.

Here is an illustration

[image: button-list]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of your title and sort that list according to the length of each title.

Largest at first and smallest at last.

Now using this list create a listView builder

now in each button use Row as its child

and Row children Icon and Text

Now use mainAxisAlignment as MainAxisAlignment.start

and wrap text to expand and align text to center

In this way I think you can achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a model which will have the title and icon and colour for it. make a list of the this model:

```
List<buttonDetails> list = [
  buttonDetails('Medium Title', Icons.density_medium, Colors.blueAccent),
  buttonDetails('Small Title', Icons.density_small, Colors.greenAccent),
  buttonDetails('VeryLarge Title', Icons.density_large, Colors.orangeAccent),
];
```

Sort it according to the length of the title's letter length, you can do it in the `initState()` like this:

```
@override
void initState() {
  list.sort((a, b) => b.title.length.compareTo(a.title.length));
  super.initState();
}
```

And show it with using `ListView.builder`:

```
ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: list.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => MaterialButton(
          minWidth: 300,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: SizeConstant.borderRadius14,
          ),
          color: list[index].color,
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Icon(
                list[index].icon,
              ),
              const SizedBox(width: 16,),
              Text(list[index].title),
            ],
          ),
        ).paddingAllDefault(),
      ),
```

And will look like this:

[image]